# How to move the squared rectangular in the document (see the picture)

Tags: geometry

[image]

I can't solve another two problems because of a error when I click on compile. could you help me?

1) A part of the document it's not printed
2)The boundary of the rectangular black is interrupted.

Thank you

```
\documentclass[addpoints,14pt]{exam}


\usepackage[italian]{babel} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 

\usepackage{anysize}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{amsbsy}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{pbox}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{cancel}
\usepackage{tabularx} 
\usepackage{booktabs} 
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{natbib} 

\usepackage{subfig}                        

\usepackage{xcolor}



\usepackage{amsmath} 
\usepackage{amssymb} 
\usepackage{mathrsfs} 

\usepackage{textcomp} 

\usepackage[centering,margin=0.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}

\linespread{1.5}                    



\frenchspacing %

\title{x}

\author{xxx}
\date{\today}


\newcommand{\abs}[1]{\lvert#1\rvert}



\begin{document}


\vspace{0.1in}
\noindent {\makebox[\textwidth]{Family name:\enspace\hrulefill} \\ \makebox[\textwidth]{Name:\enspace\hrulefill}}


\pagestyle{head}
\runningheadrule
\firstpageheader{\dots \quad \boxed{\zeta}}{XXX \\ test \thepage\ di \numpages}{\dots june 1996}
\runningheader{\dots \quad \boxed{\zeta}}
{test  \thepage\ di \numpages}
{\dots }



\begin{questions}
\question
question 1.
\makeemptybox{3in
\begin{tikzpicture}[color=gray]
%\draw[line width=0.10pt, step=1.0mm] (0,0) grid +(20cm,28cm);
%\draw[line width=0.25pt, step=5.0mm] (0,0) grid +(20cm,28cm);
\draw[line width=0.05pt, step=0.5cm] (0,0) grid +(5cm,5cm);
\end{tikzpicture}
}



%\question




\question
question 2.
\makeemptybox{3in}
%\question

\newpage
\question
question 3.
\makeemptybox{3in}
%\question

\end{questions}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Sorry, but this code is pure horror. Please edit your question and remove the not needed packages in the preamble.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're loading a bunch of packages, many of which don't make sense with `exam`. I reduced them to the pure necessary ones, add those that you *really* need. Note also that there's no `14pt` option to the class.

The command `\makeemptybox` makes an empty box, of course. So there's no provision for filling it with something and you have to go with “manual” positioning.

```
\documentclass[addpoints]{exam}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[italian]{babel} 

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{questions}

\question Question 1.\\[-\baselineskip]
\raisebox{-\dimexpr\totalheight+\baselineskip+2pt}[0pt][0pt]{%
  \makebox[0pt][l]{%
    \makebox[\linewidth][r]{%
      \hfil
      \begin{tikzpicture}[color=gray]
      \draw[line width=0.05pt, step=0.5cm] (0,0) grid +(5cm,5cm);
      \end{tikzpicture}%
      \hspace{2pt}%
    }%
  }%
}%
\makeemptybox{3in}

\end{questions}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much @egreg and I apologize if I messed up.
I rewrote the document from the document in latex I found online by Philip Hirschhorn (Department of Mathematics,
Wellesley College) "examdoc.tex" (in segunete link: http://www-math.mit.edu/~psh/) making your changes.
I hope will be of help to those who need to do a document similar to mine. I posted the text by removing some information. Thanks again.